# Yocto - Bitbake connot compile with WSL-Ubbuntu20.04LTS

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, yocto, bitbake, wsl-2

I am trying to work on my yocto project in WSL2, I cloned the project and installed all the needed packages for yocto. But my first `Bitbake` command failed with the error below. Could anyone help to figure this out.

```
Unable to create 'pyshtables.py'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pyshtables.py'
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/my-bsp/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#1)...
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/my-bsp/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#2)...
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/my-bsp/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#3)...
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/my-bsp/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#4)...
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/my-bsp/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#5)...
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/my-bsp/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#6)...
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/my-bsp/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#7)...
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/my-bsp/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#8)...
ERROR: Unable to connect to bitbake server, or start one (server startup failures would be in bitbake-cookerdaemon.log).
```

The bitbake-cookerdaemon.log content is:

```
19841 14:07:05.727937 --- Starting bitbake server pid 19841 at 2022-04-08 14:07:05.727913 ---
19841 14:07:05.852952 Started bitbake server pid 19841
19841 14:07:05.853310 Entering server connection loop
19841 14:07:05.853608 Accepting [<socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_UNIX, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=bitbake.sock>] ([])
19841 14:07:05.859170 Processing Client
19841 14:07:05.859242 Connecting Client
19841 14:07:05.864026 Running command ['setFeatures', [2]]
19841 14:07:05.864275 Command Completed
19841 14:07:05.864735 Running command ['updateConfig', {'abort': True, 'force': False, 'invalidate_stamp': None, 'dry_run': False, 'dump_signatures': [], 'extra_assume_provided': [], 'profile': False, 'prefile': [], 'postfile': [], 'server_timeout': None, 'nosetscene': False, 'setsceneonly': False, 'skipsetscene': False, 'runall': None, 'runonly': None, 'writeeventlog': None, 'build_verbose_shell': False, 'build_verbose_stdout': False, 'default_loglevel': 20, 'debug_domains': {}}, {'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'PWD': '/my-bsp/build', 'LOGNAME': 'root', 'HOME': '/root', 'BBPATH': '/my-bsp/build', 'BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE': 'ALL_PROXY BBPATH_EXTRA BB_LOGCONFIG BB_NO_NETWORK BB_NUMBER_THREADS BB_SETSCENE_ENFORCE BB_SRCREV_POLICY DISTRO FTPS_PROXY FTP_PROXY GIT_PROXY_COMMAND HTTPS_PROXY HTTP_PROXY MACHINE NO_PROXY PARALLEL_MAKE SCREENDIR SDKMACHINE SOCKS5_PASSWD SOCKS5_USER SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK STAMPS_DIR TCLIBC TCMODE all_proxy ftp_proxy ftps_proxy http_proxy https_proxy no_proxy ', 'USER': 'root', 'PATH': '/my-bsp/layers/poky/scripts:/my-bsp/layers/poky/bitbake/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin', 'LC_ALL': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'SUDO_GID': '1000', 'SUDO_COMMAND': '/usr/bin/su', 'SUDO_USER': 'azibi', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'PYTHONPATH': '/my-bsp/layers/poky/bitbake/lib:', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'DISPLAY': '127.0.0.1:0.0', 'SHLVL': '1', 'SUDO_UID': '1000', 'BUILDDIR': '/my-bsp/build', 'MAIL': '/var/mail/root', 'OLDPWD': '/my-bsp', '_': '/my-bsp/layers/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake'}, ['/my-bsp/layers/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake', 'amr-image-dev']]
19841 14:07:06.571503 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.571907 Running command ['getVariable', 'BBINCLUDELOGS']
19841 14:07:06.572063 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.572195 Running command ['getVariable', 'BBINCLUDELOGS_LINES']
19841 14:07:06.572295 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.572378 Running command ['getSetVariable', 'BB_CONSOLELOG']
19841 14:07:06.572511 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.572598 Running command ['getSetVariable', 'BB_LOGCONFIG']
19841 14:07:06.572684 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.575082 Running command ['getUIHandlerNum']
19841 14:07:06.575185 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.575283 Running command ['setEventMask', 1, 20, {'BitBake.RunQueue.HashEquiv': 19, 'BitBake.SigGen.HashEquiv': 19}, ['bb.runqueue.runQueueExitWait', 'bb.event.LogExecTTY', 'logging.LogRecord', 'bb.build.TaskFailed', 'bb.build.TaskBase', 'bb.event.ParseStarted', 'bb.event.ParseProgress', 'bb.event.ParseCompleted', 'bb.event.CacheLoadStarted', 'bb.event.CacheLoadProgress', 'bb.event.CacheLoadCompleted', 'bb.command.CommandFailed', 'bb.command.CommandExit', 'bb.command.CommandCompleted', 'bb.cooker.CookerExit', 'bb.event.MultipleProviders', 'bb.event.NoProvider', 'bb.runqueue.sceneQueueTaskStarted', 'bb.runqueue.runQueueTaskStarted', 'bb.runqueue.runQueueTaskFailed', 'bb.runqueue.sceneQueueTaskFailed', 'bb.event.BuildBase', 'bb.build.TaskStarted', 'bb.build.TaskSucceeded', 'bb.build.TaskFailedSilent', 'bb.build.TaskProgress', 'bb.event.ProcessStarted', 'bb.event.ProcessProgress', 'bb.event.ProcessFinished']]
19841 14:07:06.575376 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.575454 Running command ['getVariable', 'BB_DEFAULT_TASK']
19841 14:07:06.575535 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.575614 Running command ['setConfig', 'cmd', 'build']
19841 14:07:06.575695 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.575773 Running command ['buildTargets', ['amr-image-dev'], 'build']
19841 14:07:06.575820 Command Completed
19841 14:07:06.589838 Processing Client
/my-bsp/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/server/process.py:633: RuntimeWarning: received malformed or improperly-truncated ancillary data
  msg, ancdata, flags, addr = sock.recvmsg(1, socket.CMSG_LEN(bytes_size))
19841 14:07:06.590316 Disconnecting Client
19841 14:07:06.590490 No timeout, exiting.
19841 14:07:06.690752 Exiting
19841 14:07:06.696747 Original lockfile contents: ['19841\n']
19841 14:07:06.697218 Exiting as we could obtain the lock
```